# Calculating and displaying mean annual precipitation from CRU data

Tags: r, precipitation

I'm trying to display mean annual precipitation (MAP) data from the CRU dataset (http://data.ceda.ac.uk/badc/cru/data/cru_ts/cru_ts_4.01/data/pre/) across a specific region.

The data are monthly precipitation totals. To get MAP, I need to first calculate annual sum for each year (1901-2016), then average across all years. Ideally, I would also subset this into years 1950-2013. The CRU data come in netCDF format, which I'm unfamiliar with. Do I need to convert the netCDF to a dataframe, make the MAP calculations, then convert back to netCDF? My ultimate goal is to then export the MAP data in gridded format as a raster to ArcMap.

Below is the R code I've been using for overlaying the *overall* average CRU data on my polygon. However, the values created by `prec_rasta_mean` below are not MAP.

```
library(cruts)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

## Load shapefile to R
shp <- shapefile("GridAK_IU2016_FINAL_PolyAA83_SCSE")

## Plot shape to make sure
plot(shp)

## Retrieve data within shape file across timeRange
prec_rasta <- cruts2raster("cru_ts4.01.1901.2016.pre.dat.nc", 
timeRange=c("1950-01-01", "2013-12-31"), shp, type='brick')

## Average data across all months in timeRange
prec_rasta_mean <- calc(prec_rasta, mean)

##  Write new raster layer to wd
writeRaster(prec_rasta_mean, 'cru_prec_brick_mean.img')
```

So, I'm looking for a bit of help getting making the calculations in netCDF, then I think the code above should take care of the rest.

The polygon that I'm using was created in ArcMap and the shapefile is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_eqTercwIH2d01tekdaY2tSbEU/view?usp=sharing

Bit of a novice playing with spatial data in R (and ArcMap).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution (with help from colleagues).

The following code gets MAP for each grid cell, averaged over the timerange of interest (1950-2013).  Basically I created a vector that could be used to index each year, summed across years, then took the average of the whole timerange.

```
# create vector to serve as index
num_years <- rep(1:113, each=12)

# sum annual precipitation across months for each year, indexed using 
# num_years
rasta_sum <- stackApply(prec_rasta, indices=num_years, fun=sum)

# average annual sum for each cell across years
rasta_mean <- calc(rasta_sum, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

In the end, I didn't need to manipulate the netCDF file at all.  Just converted to raster using `cruts2raster` function, then performed calculations with `raster`.